# How to scroll in TabPages/TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tabcontrol with 3 pages. Within the tabpages are placed listviews. The listviews can be bigger than the tabpage itself.

I wanna add scrollbars on the tabpages

I tried to solve this with the following source:

```
  lvwAlbums.Parent = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1];
            lvwAlbums.Left = 0;
            lvwAlbums.Top = 0;
            lvwAlbums.Width = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1].Width - 35;
            lvwAlbums.Height = 1000;// pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1].Height;
            lvwAlbums.SmallImageList = iltListView;
            lvwAlbums.FullRowSelect = true;
            lvwAlbums.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;

 foreach (TabPage _Page in pctlDatabeheer.TabPages)
            {
                _Page.AutoScroll = true;
                _Page.AutoScrollMargin = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
                _Page.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(_Page.Width, _Page.Height);
            }
```

But the scroll are not shown. What do I wrong?

Can anybody help me?

Thank yopu for your help.

Comment: Why don't you make your list views Scrollable ?

Comment: How do you do that? With Scrollable = true; I didn't see any difference.

Comment: lvwAlbums.Parent = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1];
            lvwAlbums.Left = 0;
            lvwAlbums.Top = 0;
            lvwAlbums.Width = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1].Width - 35;
            lvwAlbums.Height = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1].Height;
            lvwAlbums.SmallImageList = iltListView;
            lvwAlbums.FullRowSelect = true;
            lvwAlbums.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;

Comment: It is the anchoring.  Remove your anchoring to the bottom.  Please remember to upvote and accept if this helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a new Visual Studio WinForms project.  Kept the form designer completely empty and used your code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Make TabControl
    TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage());
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage());
    tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(tabControl1);

    // Make long ListView and add to first tab
    ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    listView1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    listView1.Height = 1000;
    tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(listView1);

    // Your code
    foreach (TabPage _Page in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        _Page.AutoScroll = true;
        _Page.AutoScrollMargin = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        _Page.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(_Page.Width, _Page.Height);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly fine.  I suspect you have something else wrong but I can't see that or troubleshoot it without seeing your code.

**EDIT:  Now that you posted some more code, your issue is with your list box:**

```
lvwAlbums.Parent = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1];
lvwAlbums.Left = 0;
lvwAlbums.Top = 0;
lvwAlbums.Width = pctlDatabeheer.TabPages[1].Width - 35;
lvwAlbums.Height = 1000;
lvwAlbums.SmallImageList = iltListView;
lvwAlbums.FullRowSelect = true;
// Here is the issue!
// Do not anchor to the bottom or scrolling won't work
lvwAlbums.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
```

Don't anchor the control to the bottom.  That is causing you the issue.  You cannot anchor to the bottom and then scroll.  The other anchors are fine.

Comment: Thank you. But it is much complexer. I've a panel added as parent for the listview. (For so far). But the TabControl is bigger than the form. Now I'm looking for the reason why?